# How can I see exactly what has changed between two images with a difference in brightness?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-cs5

I have two images that are the same, except that one has an adjustment in its brightness.

Is there a way to compute the difference of these images in Photoshop somehow to see what has changed from one image to another?

Image 1:

[image: original]

Image 2 (with brightness adjustment):

[image: with brightness adjustment]

Comment: What exactly are you looking for as the output? A map of the pixels that have changed? A numeric value representing the amount of change (perhaps in "stops"?) Or something else? What do you want to do with this information once you have it?

Comment: @mattdm I want to the brightness factor that transforms the one into the other image.

Answer (score 2):

If you layer those in Photoshop and use subtract or difference blend modes, you'll end up with a result that should show the relative difference of each pixel.

Use that result to create a mask (Image > Apply Image, target layer mask)

Then starting with the first image, add an exposure adjustment layer, and use the above mask - I would expect you'd get something close to the second image.